# Get contents of link tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, stylesheet

Has anyone had luck getting the contents of a stylesheet loaded with a  tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the content of already-loaded stylesheets without an additional HTTP request, the best place to start is the `document.styleSheets` object. Here's documentation (from MDC, but IE's implementation is largely similar): https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.styleSheets

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery**

```
var link = $('#linkID');
$.get(link.attr('href'), '', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

The fact that I am way too lazy to write the native JS way proves that you should use jQuery.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com)

Comment: Problem with this is that its doing a 2nd GET request to load the data. Already know how to do that. Thanks though.